# Initialize servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet class:

```
public class WarServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private MyController controller;

 .
 .
 .
}
```

I want to grab an instance of MyController (different controller each time) from outside the class (eg. initialize it) via some set method or constructor. How can I achieve this? (Running the server just uses the default constructor and I have no control over it)

EDIT: new problem

I worked it out by putting a static instance of MyController in the class which holds main.

I used a getter to get that instance into the servlet with every call to request() and it returns null.

My only conclusion is that when main() exits it deletes the static members of the class?

Comment: What do you mean by _different controller each time_? Each request? Each server startup?

Comment: There is an `init` method. And also, there is CDI.

Comment: Each server startup. If it would be each request I'd just ask the client for the info.

Comment: @SJuan76 please elaborate on CDI. What is it?

Comment: CDI is a very important technology in enterprise applications - Google will happily explain what it is. The `init()` method is probably sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Init() doesn't receive parameters which is bad for me (I want to pass the object's reference) so I can't override that.

Comment: Where would these parameters _come from_?? The Servlet container creates the servlet and calls `init`. How do you image it would work any other way? You need to _pull_ dependencies into your servlet or have CDI _inject_ them. There is no other way.

Comment: At least I thought so, can you have a look at my edit?